# How to automatically logout an inactive user in your CMS PHP

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, content-management-system, logout

I am trying to force log out an inactive user from my CMS. The timeout value is stored in a value called PREF_TIMEOUT in my database. Ive borrowed this code and modified it a little. The code does not seem to be doing anything. Does anyone know of a better method of doing this or can spot what is breaking it?

```
<?php
function init() {
    parent:: init();
    self::logoutInactiveUser();
}

$timeout = mysql_query("SELECT PREF_TIMEOUT FROM preferences WHERE PREF_ID = '1'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($timeout);

function logoutInactiveUser() {
    $inactivityLimit = $timeout * 60; // Converted to seconds
    $sessionStart = Session::get('session_start_time');
    if (isset($sessionStart)){
        $elapsed_time = time() - Session::get('session_start_time');
        if ($elapsed_time >= $inactivityLimit) {
            $member = Member::currentUser();
            if($member) $member->logOut();
            Session::clear_all();
            Director::redirect(Director::baseURL() . 'Security/login');
        }
    }
    Session::set('session_start_time', time());
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer to my answer at the link: [Logout an inactive user using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639980/logout-an-inactive-user-using-php/30641506#30641506) .

As per your current code, the issue is your Queries 

`$timeout = mysql_query("SELECT PREF_TIMEOUT FROM preferences WHERE PREF_ID = '1'");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($timeout);`

are outside the function **logoutInactiveUser()**, due to which the variable **$timeout** will not have any data from your database. Moving the code inside the function should help you.